# What does Particular Software Service Platform exactly is?

Tags: web-services, nservicebus, soa

Someone told be about this Service Platform: http://particular.net/ for implementing SOA oriented applications.

I really find it a bit confusing at first glance, so i would like to ask some questions about it:

- Services are SOAP or REST?
- How are data contracts and service contracts specified?
- Are this services externalizable to outside consumers via WSDL metadata endpoints?
- A service not implemented in .net (java, ruby) can be inserted in the service bus?
- Which is the protocol used for messaging?
- What are your general thoughts about this service platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full disclosure, I'm the founder of the Particular Service Platform, but I'll try to keep my answers as objective as possible:

> Services are SOAP or REST?

While the platform allows the use of WCF to expose endpoints for consumption by 3rd parties, the focus is on queuing - MSMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.

> How are data contracts and service contracts specified?

Contracts are message-oriented from a philosophical perspective, but in practice they're just regular POCO classes and interfaces.

> Are this services externalizable to outside consumers via WSDL metadata endpoints?

See the WCF comment above.

> A service not implemented in .net (java, ruby) can be inserted in the service bus?

Interop can be done via WCF but the preferred model would be to use either ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, or WebSphereMQ.

> Which is the protocol used for messaging?

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "protocol" beyond the queues mentioned above, but we support XML, Binary, and JSON serialization out of the box and also enable you to plug in your own serialization mechanism.

> What are your general thoughts about this service platform?

As one of the owners of this platform, I feel my necessarily biased answer wouldn't contribute much on this point.